# Does the OMG provide a version of the MOF 2 specification as an XMI document?

Tags: specifications

I can't seem to find one on the OMG's website.

I need this document for bootstrapping the M3 model so I can load the UML metamodel  (M2)

http://www.omg.org/spec/MOF/2.0/

I can build on my self by drudging through the PDF specification, however I was hoping to find a prebuilt model.

Comment: Question no good?  This is programming related!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah here it is - looks like it's only available to members:

http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?ptc/2006-06-06

Drats.